# NetBeans 8.2 Opens GUI windows and its components really tiny (Win 10, Surface Pro 3)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8

I am building some Swing Application in NetBeans, using the GUI it offers to do so. When I run the application it opens the window really really small, and its very hard to use because of that. I just fixed the NetBeans issue of all of its text and components being very small by setting `-J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=false`. But this only made the change to NetBeans, not the applications that it opens.
Any idea how I can fix this? In the picture below, you can see NetBeans in the back and the size I work on, compared to the window that was opened when I ran the application. (In the picture below, the size of the window that was opened, was the old size of the components in NetBeans before setting dpiaware to false)

Screen shot of my tiny window :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sz3C.jpg]

Comment: Wow...Curious, what is your current Screen Resolution?

Comment: @DevilsHnd I found the solution there, it was not scaling some apps correctly. its weird because everything else looks and works fine, it was only NetBeans that was having the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From DevilsHnd's Comment, I went to look at my resolution and I noticed some text on that page in the Scale and Layout sections that said "Some apps will not scale properly until you logout". 
[Computer Display Settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5fBy.jpg)

Which was weird because I turn off by surface when ever I stop using it, and I turn it on and log in when ever I get back on. But, I clicked that link to log out, and when I logged back in the app window was the correct size =). Yay dumb luck!!!
[App window showing as the correct size.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUbZF.jpg)

**Note:** I use 3 monitors at home, this issue might have been caused because of something to do with that.